Why isn't my click and release button working (Selenium)
I am trying to scrape the following site travelocity.com.
My code should do the following:

enter the site
scroll down to the bottom of the page
click button "Show more" (which loads more results)
scroll down to the bottom of the page
click button "Show more" (which loads more results)
etc.

But when it click the "Show more" button it does not update more results, it just keeps clicking on it and nothing happens. What could be the issue? I presume the site detects I am a bot.
It is this button at the bottom of the page:

My current code for clicking and releasing the button is the following:
try:
   show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Show more')]")
   action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
   action_chains.click_and_hold(show_more_button).perform()
   time.sleep(1)
   action_chains.release().perform()
   time.sleep(5)

except NoSuchElementException:
   print("All results are loaded.")
   break

I have also tried:
show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Show more')]")
show_more_button.click()

but it didn't work as well.
Here is the full code:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

URL = 'https://www.travelocity.com/Hotel-Search?destination=San%20Francisco%20%28and%20vicinity%29%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States%20of%20America&regionId=178305&latLong=37.7874%2C-122.4082&flexibility=0_DAY&d1=2024-05-08&startDate=2024-05-08&d2=2024-05-22&endDate=2024-05-22&adults=2&rooms=1&theme=&userIntent=&semdtl=&useRewards=false&sort=RECOMMENDED'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(4)

while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        show_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Show more')]")

        action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
        action_chains.click_and_hold(show_more_button).perform()

        time.sleep(0.5)

        action_chains.release().perform()
        
        time.sleep(3)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("All results are loaded.")
        break

driver.quit()


That website detects Selenium, and then blocks data for that. You'll need to use a stealthy Python Selenium framework (such as https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to get around that limitation.
pip install seleniumbase - and then run the code below with python:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    url = "https://www.travelocity.com/Hotel-Search?destination=San%20Francisco%20%28and%20vicinity%29%2C%20California%2C%20United%20States%20of%20America&regionId=178305&latLong=37.7874%2C-122.4082&flexibility=0_DAY&d1=2024-05-08&startDate=2024-05-08&d2=2024-05-22&endDate=2024-05-22&adults=2&rooms=1&theme=&userIntent=&semdtl=&useRewards=false&sort=RECOMMENDED"
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 6)
    sb.driver.uc_click("section > button.uitk-button-secondary")

    breakpoint()

See SeleniumBase/help_docs/uc_mode for info on SeleniumBase's stealth mode (UC Mode), which is used for evading bot-detection.
Also note that the uc_click(selector) method needs a CSS Selector to do a full stealth click. ("section > button.uitk-button-secondary" is the CSS Selector for the Show more button.)

Even though I have pip install selenium base, when I run the program I get "No module name seleniumbase". What could be the issue?

seleniumbase is one word, not two.

I have entered pip install seleniumbase but sitll no luck.

You probably have multiple versions of Python on your machine. Specify the same one for pip that you use to run scripts. Eg. python3 / python3 -m pip install seleniumbase.

Can you tell me, is there in documentation how to scroll the window, and if there is can you send me the link? Thank you.
